# Problem with Django project while trying to dockerise

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to run my Django project as a webserver.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.3-slim

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables  
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1  

#install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools
                        
COPY ./webserver /usr/src/app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN python manage.py makemigrations
RUN python manage.py migrate

EXPOSE 8000

CMD [ "python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000" ]
```

While the makemigrations is running, I get the error that the DB tables don't exist. I also tried to run makemigrations after the container started, but that also does not work and I get the same error.

I'm using a SQLite3 DB.

I made the GitHub repository public if you would like to test it for yourself: [my GitHub repository](https://github.com/Hanni007112/ServerWake_public)

Comment: You can't run migrations or otherwise interact with a database in a Dockerfile.  The `rake db:migrate` question looks Ruby-oriented but has a good explanation of the Docker mechanics involved.  I've also linked this to a Django-specific question on handling migrations that describes a couple of best practices.